# Ninject not binding classes from assembly correctly

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

Concerning the following code:

```
kernel.Bind(scan => scan.FromAssemblyContaining<IMediator>()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .BindDefaultInterface()
    .Configure(o => o.InRequestScope()));
```

I am making this call from a container class in my Web project. I would expect that other projects that contain IMediator anywhere in that project would be picked up by this bind and all classes in that project bound to default interfaces. However, this isn't the case.

I'm noticing that none of the classes in outside projects are bound. I'm wondering, at the lowest level possible, what this call is doing.

- What assemblies is it looking through and shouldn't it include every project in my solution?
- To what capacity do I need to use IMediator in other projects for it to be picked up here?
- What's missing in order for me to get the expected behavior: This scans through all my projects, sees that IMediator is being used in that code, gets all the classes in that project, binds them according to default convention.
- Am I completely off and missing something here? Any clarification?

Clarifications:

- I am correctly using default bind conventions
- For the sake of this question, I'm not concerned with other setup regarding handlers. I'm specifically trying to understand this exact call and why my non-handler, non-request classes aren't binding.

Comment: Is this Ninject? It's not clear at all.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for calling this out @DavidG! Complete brain failure, meant Ninject, not MediatR. Edited.